# Bulk insert flat utf-8 with áåóñ

Tags: sql-server, utf-8

I have a flat file witch I would like to bulk insert into SQL server (2016).

```
 BULK INSERT table FROM 'path\flatfile.dat'
   WITH 
      (
        FORMATFILE='path\fileformat.fmt', 
        CODEPAGE = '65001', 
        DATAFILETYPE = 'Char'
      );
```

Flat file has no field terminator:

```
                      9999030000000001001ab Baujahr                                                  0
                      9999030000000001004from construction year                                      0
                      9999030000000001006à partir d'année de construction                            0
                      9999030000000001007da anno                                                     0
                      9999030000000001008año construcción desde                                      0
                      9999030000000001009Vanaf bouwjaar                                              0
                      9999030000000001010fra byggeår                                                 0
                      9999030000000001011från årsmodell                                              0
                      9999030000000001012fra årsmodell                                               0
                      9999030000000001013Vuosimallista                                               0
```

but in format file I set the lenght of field

```
12.0
    7
    1       SQLCHAR           0       22      ""         1     Field1            ""
    2       SQLCHAR           0       4       ""         2     field2            ""
    3       SQLCHAR           0       3       ""         3     field3            ""
    4       SQLCHAR           0       9       ""         4     field4            ""
    5       SQLCHAR           0       3       ""         5     field             ""
    6       SQLCHAR           0       60      ""         6     Textfield         ""
    7       SQLCHAR           0       1       "\r\n"     7     flag              ""
```

The other files I have with similar format works great except this one.
The error I'm getting is truncation of rows which contains caracters áåóñ...

```
    Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 3, column 7 (LFlag).
Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 5, column 7 (LFlag).
Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 7, column 7 (LFlag).
Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
```

any ideas ?

Comment: What are the datatypes of the columns in your target table?

Comment: datatypes are nvarchar with a lenght same as lenght in fmt file (Field1[nvarchar](22))...

Comment: Untested, but you might need to use `SQLNCHAR` not `SQLCHAR` as the data type for each column in the format file (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189110.aspx)

Comment: allready tried it, SQLNCHAR and SQLNVARCHAR but I get truncation error for each of the fields  
`Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 4`

Comment: The format file doesn't seem to match the example data; the file contains 91 characters per line, but the format file allows 102

Comment: Fixed, when I copied example data some blanks got lost. in the data file there are 102 characters

Comment: Are you sure the file is UTF8? `à` uses two bytes in UTF8

Comment: yes, it is UFT8 and I'm almost positive that the error I'm getting is because of two bytes per character (some of them). But I don't know how to correct the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear whether the use of format files is fully supported by BCP when working with UTF-8 - your experience suggests that it isn't.
It appears that there's some confusion between byte count and character count when importing a UTF-8 file. I think this is possibly a bug in BCP.

With the following test table

```
USE tempdb
GO
CREATE table t1
(f1  nvarchar(max),
f2  nvarchar(max),
f3  nvarchar(max),
f4  nvarchar(max),
f5  nvarchar(max),
f6  nvarchar(max),
f7  nvarchar(max))
```

I was able to import your file using the format file in the question, and the same `BULK INSERT` command.

However, what's notable is that the final column (`f7` in my table) is left-padded with a number of leading spaces equal to the number double-byte characters in column 6.

On row 3 (column 6 value `à partir d'année de construction`), column 7 is padded with two spaces. The same is true of rows 5 and 8, which also have two double-byte characters.

On row 9 (column 6 value `fra årsmodell`), column 7 is padded with one space. The same is true of row 7.

It looks like the byte-count and character-count are not being tracked correctly by BCP.

Assuming the format of your input file is fixed, the only option I can see to work around this issue would be to import the data file into a table with single `nvarchar(max)` column, then use `LEFT`, `RIGHT` and `SUBSTRING` statements to extract data values from the rows:

```
CREATE TABLE t2
(f1  nvarchar(max))

BULK INSERT t2 FROM 'file\location' WITH (CODEPAGE = '65001',DATAFILETYPE = 'Char' );

SELECT LEFT(f1,22), SUBSTRING(f1,23,4), SUBSTRING(f1,27,3),
       SUBSTRING(f1,30,9), SUBSTRING(f1,39,3), SUBSTRING(f1,42,60), 
       SUBSTRING(f1,102,1)
FROM t2
```

**Edit**

Tested an XML format file, which doesn't work correctly either. Although using an XML format file allows the file to load without error, the value for column 7 is lost and replaced by a space.

Format file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<BCPFORMAT  
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format"  
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
  <RECORD>  
    <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="22"/>  
    <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="4"/>  
    <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="3"/>  
    <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="9"/>  
    <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="3"/>  
    <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="60"/>  
    <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="1"/>  
    <FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n"  />
  </RECORD>  
  <ROW>  
    <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="C1" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />  
    <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="C2" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />  
    <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="C3" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />  
    <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="C4" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />  
    <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="C5" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />  
    <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="C6" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />  
    <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="C7" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />  
  </ROW>  
</BCPFORMAT>
```

(The `BULK INSERT` command is the same as in the question, other than the format file name.)